# React Native Expo create apk

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk

I have created some apps with React Native using Expo but this is my first time trying to build the app to update it to Play Store and App Store, first of all, I would like to make an apk to try with my devices on android which I think will be easier than iOS.

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "todolist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
   },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "expo-cli": "^6.3.10"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have watched a lot of videos, read tons of webs and tutorials, but I CAN NOT create an apk, I tryed this command: `npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file App.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` And it works, but when I try `./gradlew assembleDebug` it doesn't, giving to me all of this. (I know pictures of code is not a good idea, but this is too big)

[image]

I created an `eas.json` file with the next code:

```
{
"build": {
    "preview": {
        "android": {
            "buildType": "apk"
        }
    },
    "preview2": {
        "android": {
            "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
        }
    },
    "preview3": {
        "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
}
}
```

I logged in to my expo account and when I run the next code: `eas build -p android --profile preview` it gives me the next error: `✖ Build failed  Android build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.`

If I'm honest, I do not know what to do next, I am completely block, could anyone please help?

PD: If you need to see more code, just let me know what file do you need.

Answer (score 0):

According what you are telling us, you have an bare workflow expo project. In this case, I would suggest you two ways to get this done.

The first one is generating the Android App Bundle file (.aab). This is the Android publishing format compatible with Google Play. Run this command for this:

```
npx react-native build-android --mode=release
```

The output will be placed in android folder: `/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab`

The another one is generating the APK. So you can run these commands for this:

`./gradlew clean` //just for cleaning build folder

`./gradlew assembleRelease` //for generating the apk

The output will be placed in android folder: `android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for you answer but, I do not have an android folder, so that commands give me error because android folder does not exist, how do I create it?